# PHP: Type hinting in namespaces not working?

Tags: php, type-hinting

I'm trying to do some type hinting with PHP 5.6 while using namespaces and I keep getting errors like this:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
>   NS\MyClass::__construct() must be an instance of string, string
>   given, called in
>   /Users/username/path/MyClass.php
>   on line 9 and defined in
>   /Users/username/path/MySubClass.php
>   on line 52

The code basically looks like this:

```
<?php namespace NS;

class MySubClass extends MyClass {
    public function __construct(string $mystring) {
        parent::__construct($mystring);
    }
}

?>
```

and

```
<?php namespace NS;

class MyClass {
    public function __construct() {
        // do stuff
    }
}

?>
```

so when I call the constructor of the Subclass with a String like

```
$x = new \NS\MySubClass("hello");
```

the error shows up. 
It also does NOT work with a

```
public function __construct(\string $mystring) {
```

How can I typehint a basic type while in a namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to typehint strings in PHP 5.6. Support for this feature was added in PHP 7.

[More info on typehinting for functions in PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)